# GXT 3.1.2 / GWT 2.7 [WARN] Resource 'com/sencha/gxt/core/public/clear.gif' was located via ClassLoader

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am integrating GXT 3.1.2 with GWT 2.7, during the compilation phase I obtain a dirty warning message

**[WARN] Resource 'com/sencha/gxt/core/public/clear.gif' was located via ClassLoader. As a result changes in that resource will not be reflected in per-file recompiles. It should be registered via   or  entry in your .gwt.xml. In a future version of GWT, we will remove this fallback and your application will stop compiling**

As it's part of the gxt framework I don't know how to fix that. According to this [page](https://docs.sencha.com/gxt/getting_started/Versions.html) gxt 3.1.2 and gwt 2.7 are compatible. I tried to copy manually the file clear.gif in my public folder but the warning message is still here, any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error in your application, but a warning that future versions of GWT may change how this operates. GXT needs to change before then, but to continue to correctly support older versions of GWT, then cannot change yet.

The fix is to avoid using the implicit `<public>` tag in a .gwt.xml, and move to the new `<resource>` tag, or abuse `<source>` to add the public directory as if it contained Java sources.

This warning is still not an error in GWT 2.8-beta1, so it should be assumed that the final 2.8 release will not break this either. With that said, there are other changes in GWT 2.8 that are breaking, and an updated copy of 3.1.x will likely need to be released to compensate for them (changes in how generator contexts access resources, which breaks the XTemplates generator).

Comment: So I have no way to remove these warning messages ? This is a bit annoying because I have four warning messages like this during the compilation time, it pollutes the logs... I think I will go back to the gwt version 2.6.1

Comment: If you're interested in GXT 4.0, these issues are fixed in 4.0. 4.0 works great with 2.8-beta1 too.